# How to plot mean of group means in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, confidence-interval

I have the following data(dat)

```
V  W  X  Y  Z
1  2  3  4  5
2  2  3  4  5
3  2  3  4  5
4  2  3  4  5
```

I wish to plot a **line** with the mean of group means For eg. in the above dataset, the overall mean across all groups is 3.3. So along with the graph for group means, I require a line with the mean of group mean.

The code for the simple group means is as follows:

```
dat1 <- gather(dat)#long format
ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = key, y = value)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", colour = "red", size  = 1)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this, without computing the group mean and CI externally and then calling the value in ggplot2?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you comment prior to down voting questions.

Comment: @akrun : Yes, I have made the edit.

Comment: Could you check whether the below posted solution is what you are looking for?

Comment: Why should there ba a confidence interval? I see no mention of any statistical assumptions that would support one? The question taken as a whole makes me suggest you need a statistician.

Comment: @42-: I agree with you. In context of my original data and the context n which I am placing it..I can see why. But for this question, I have dropped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
   mutate(all = mean(unlist(.)) + rnorm(n())) %>%
    gather() %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x=key, y=value)) +
          stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", colour = "red", size  = 1)
```

Comment: Do I have to use some other library for mutate? I get this error Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "mutate"

Comment: @Biotechgeek  It is in `dplyr`.  Nowadays, you can just install `tidyverse` and it contains all these packages

Comment: It does do the trick! But how can I change the code such that it makes a line and a confidence interval associated with this mean of group mean?

Comment: @Biotechgeek  You can add a random number to the `mean` ie. `mean(unlist(.)) + rnorm(n())`

Comment: @Bioteckgeek or perhaps `sd1 <- dat %>% summarise_each(funs(sd))%>% unlist() %>% mean;  dat %>% mutate(all = mean(unlist(.)) + sd1) %>%`

Comment: I don't understand what you did in the last comment

Comment: @Biotechgeek I think I made a mistake in that comment.  You may need something like standard deviation  for each row